# Linux single instance shell script fails to open in correct workspace at times

Tags: linux, shell, switch-statement, instance, workspace

I have written the following Linux shell script through snippits gleaned from the web (I'm very new to shell scripts), its purpose is to ensure only a single instance of a programme is run with the added option of specifying which workspace a programme will open to.

I'm sure much of the code could be better constructed, however it works with one bug, when some, like Thunderbird, are opened they ignore the workspace switch unless the workaround I've added is used, but why? and is there a better way?

The script uses wmctrl: sudo apt-get install wmctrl

Usage: single-switch programme_name [-ws(int)] where (int) is number of workspace (must exist), the -ws param must be the last listed

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ $1 ] ; then exit ; fi
if [ "?" = "$1" ] ; then
    FILE=$(echo "$0" | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev) # extract filename from path
    echo "usage $FILE <program name> [-ws(int)]"
    exit 1;
fi
TITLE=$1
NAME=""
for var in "$@"; do  [ "$(echo ${var} | head -c3)" != '-ws' ] && NAME="$NAME $var" ; done # remove our param from command
ntharg() {  shift $1 ; echo $1 ; }
PARAM=`ntharg $# "$@"` # get the last param
if [ "-ws" != "$(echo ${PARAM} | head -c3)" ]; then PARAM=-1 ; # check its ours
else
PARAM=$( echo "$PARAM" | egrep -o '[0-9]+' ) # get the number
PARAM=$((PARAM-1)) # decrement
fi
if  [ $PARAM -ge 0 ] ; then 
    wmctrl -x -a "$TITLE" || ( wmctrl -s $PARAM && zenity --title="Launch $TITLE" --warning --text="$TITLE is starting" --timeout="1" ; $NAME ) 
    # dummy message otherwise some (ie thunderbird) ignore switch
else
   wmctrl -x -a "$TITLE" || $NAME & # no switch, just raise or run programme
fi

# Done.
#
```

Comment: What window manager is this supposed to work with?

Comment: Its wmctrl that interacts with the window manager and that is stated to work with EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Managers. I`m using it with KDE in this instance.